# Pyside6 QDateEdit causes system crash

Tags: qt, ubuntu, pyside6, wayland, gnome-shell

It seems like that in Pyside6, closing the popup of a QDateEdit causes a system crash.
MWE:

```
from PySide6 import QtWidgets


class DateEditGui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.vertical_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.date_picker = QtWidgets.QDateEdit()
        self.date_picker.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.vertical_layout.addWidget(self.date_picker)

        widget.setLayout(self.vertical_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
window = DateEditGui()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

When I execute this script, the window appears and I can select via a click the calendar popup. When I click again on the arrow or try to close the popup in any other way, my whole system crashes.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 with Python 3.10.6, Pyside6 version 6.4.0.1.
Is this a known Qt bug, related to Pyside6 only or an Ubuntu issue?

EDIT: The MWE works with Pyside2 and otherwise unchanged settings. Another test revealed that the QDateEdit works on Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.9 and Pyside6.

EDIT2: This bug seems to be related to gnome-shell, since /var/log/syslog prints

```
gnome-shell[4736]: GNOME Shell crashed with signal 11
```

Unfortunately, there is no more information in the syslog.
If I switch from Wayland to Xorg, the issue is gone.

Comment: Since this is most certainly a bug, you should report it.

Comment: Where would be the right place?

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io (report it as a Qt bug, not a PySide one)